# How to copy excell cell value using vba

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to copy cell values from one excel sheet to another. For this I have written the following code:

```
Dim p As Variant

For p = 2 To 12000

If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(p, 1).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(p, 7).Value Then


Sheet1.Cells(p, 9).Value = Sheet2.Cells(p, 7).Value

End If


Next p
```

The comparison is done only the copying is not completing...can you please help me with this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working for me:

```
Dim p As Long
For p = 2 To 12000
    If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(p,1).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(p,7).Value Then
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(p,9).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(p,7).Value
    End If
Next p
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use this:

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(p, 9).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(p, 7).Value
```

Comment: Well, I guess my suggestion was same (sans the lines for `For` and `If`) as @Matteo's answer which you have chosen. So, it should work. I should have mentioned the omission of the obvious code lines.